# Getting "InternalServerError" while using Mongo with Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, internal-server-error

I am new to Node js programming. Trying to write a simple user create using.. code along with the stack track is given below. Appreciate any help as to what is causing this..

users-add.mjs:

```
'use strict';

const util = require('util');
const restify = require('restify-clients');
console.log("starting...");
var client = restify.createJsonClient({url: 'http://localhost:'+process.env.PORT,  version: '*'});

console.log("starting...2  ");
client.basicAuth('them', 'D4ED43C0-8BD6-4FE2-B358-7C0E230D11EF'); 
client.post('/create-user', { username: "me", password: "w0rd", provider: "local", 
  familyName: "GUD", givenName: "RG", middleName: "Ud", emails: [], photos: []}, 
  (err, req, res, obj) => {
  console.log("starting...4  ");
    if(err) {
      console.log("starting...5");
      console.error(err.stack);
    }
    else {
      console.log("starting...6");
      console.log('Created ' + util.inspect(obj));
    }
});
console.log("starting...3  ");
```

Here is the error I'm getting.. Surprisingly the server side code is able to insert the record into MongoDB, and yet I get this error..

```
InternalServerError: {}
    at Object.createHttpErr (/Users/raviguduru/node-web-dev/chapter8/users/node_modules/restify-clients/lib/helpers/errors.js:91:26)
    at ClientRequest.onResponse (/Users/raviguduru/node-web-dev/chapter8/users/node_modules/restify-clients/lib/HttpClient.js:309:26)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:583:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:17)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:456:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
```

Pls help.

Comment: Are you getting this error in the server or the client? If it is in the client, are there any other logs(from the ones you added in the code) around this stack-trace?

Comment: I was getting it from the server side but seen on the client side. I figured out the problem. The internal server error comes when we have MongoDBClient calls not wrapped in try/catch blocks. After I included try/catch blocks, they went away. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved now.. The internal server error comes when we have MongoDBClient calls not wrapped in try/catch blocks. After I included try/catch blocks, they went away.